# Why does tf.nn.seq2seq.embedding_attention_decoder use tf.nn.embeddin_lookup without tf.device('/cpu:0')?

Tags: tensorflow

From the following commit, `tf.nn.seq2seq.embedding_attention_decoder` uses `tf.nn.embeddin_lookup` without `tf.device('/cpu:0')`.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/8cc567bf9703e14f0e16595eb9f220859a5eff20#diff-cf94d06c60c56f954b1926fb6e53cb11L86

Why `tf.nn.seq2seq.embedding_attention_decoder` no longer use `tf.device('/cpu:0')`?
Is `tf.nn.embeddin_lookup` currently implemented on the GPU?

Comment: In v0.12, `seq2seq_model` no longer uses `tf.nn.embeddin_lookup`, so I changed the title from `seq2seq_model` to `tf.nn.seq2seq.embedding_attention_decoder`.